# When Accessing OpenAmplify from QueryPath my HTTP request fails/times out. Why?

Tags: php, http, querypath

WHen I run this script from cmd.exe [command line] on WAMP I get:

```
 Could not retrieve data from OpenAmplify.file_get_contents(http://portal
tnx.openamplify.com/AmplifyWeb/AmplifyThis?apiKey=MY_API_KEY_GOES_HERE): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  (C:\wamp\www\Learning_Query_Pa
th\src\QueryPath\QueryPath.php: 4053)
```

When I run this script from localhost via firefox browser [v 19.0] I get:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\Learning_Query_Path\src\QueryPath\QueryPath.php on line 4525
```

Here is the script I used:

```
    <?php

require 'src/QueryPath/QueryPath.php';

$url = 'http://portaltnx.openamplify.com/AmplifyWeb/AmplifyThis?';
$key = 'I_PUT_MY_API_KEY_HERE';
$text = 'I_PUT_TEXT_HERE';

$params = array(
  'apiKey' => $key,
);

$url .= http_build_query($params);

$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'user_agent' => 'QueryPath/2.0',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-url-encoded',
    'content' => http_build_query(array('inputText' => $text)),
  ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($options);
try {
  $qp = qp($url, NULL, array('context' => $context));
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  print "Could not retrieve data from OpenAmplify." . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

    $qp->find('ProperNouns>TopicResult>Topic>Name')->slice(0, 20);


$out = qp(QueryPath::HTML_STUB, 'body')->append('<ul/>')->find('ul');


foreach ($qp as $name) {
  $out->append('<li>' . $name->text() . '</li>');
}

$out->writeHTML();


?>
```

How can I make this work?

P.S. Open Amplify is a web service which takes the text provided and after analysing it, returns alot of interesting things about it. I am really keen on making this work and big fan of QueryPath, so I am only interested in suggestions on how to make it work with QueryPath!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend the timeout, you can use the 'timeout' name/value pair inside of the 'http' options. E.g. put it under here:

`'content' => ...
'timeout' => 120.0`

(Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)

My guess, though, is that something else is amiss. You might use `file_get_contents()` instead of `qp()` to fetch the file, and then pass the string into QueryPath. At least from that point you will be debugging the network issue, and not QueryPath.

For working with OpenAmplify, I've also had great luck with using the CURL API, but that is a little more complex than the built-in PHP stream wrapper (Reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: When I replace [$qp = qp($url, NULL, array('context' => $context));] with [$qp1 = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
  $qp = qp($qp1);] in the code above and run the script from CLI I get:
[PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://portaltnx.openamplify.com/AmplifyWeb/A
mplifyThis?apiKey=MY_API): failed to open stream: HTTP
 request failed!  in C:\wamp\www\Learning_Query_Path\querypath1.php on line 43
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Learning_Query_Path\querypath1.php:0
PHP   2. file_get_contents() C:\wamp\www\Learning_Query_Path\querypath1.php:43] To be continued...

Comment: [Call Stack:
    0.0006     241600   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\Learning_Query_Path\querypath1.p
hp:0
    0.0149    1451840   2. file_get_contents() C:\wamp\www\Learning_Query_Path\q
uerypath1.php:43

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.or
g/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charse
t=utf-8"><title>Untitled</title></head><body><ul></ul></body></html>] Any suggestions? I will get back to you regarding cURL because I havent learnt it yet-thats what I was trying to avoid, but I guess its inevitable.

Answer (score 0):

try hitting this url. This should work
http://portaltnx20.openamplify.com/AmplifyWeb_v21/AmplifyThis

Comment: When i try this url with the code above, I get:
Could not retrieve data from OpenAmplify.file_get_contents(http://portaltnx20.openamplify.com/AmplifyWeb_v21/AmplifyThis?apiKey=MY_API_KEY): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable (C:\wamp\www\Learning_Query_Path\src\QueryPath\QueryPath.php: 4053)

Comment: If I use this URL [Web_v21 changed to Web_v20), however I get:
Could not retrieve data from OpenAmplify.file_get_contents(http://portaltnx20.openamplify.com/AmplifyWeb_v20/AmplifyThis?apiKey=MY_API_KEY): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden (C:\wamp\www\Learning_Query_Path\src\QueryPath\QueryPath.php: 4053)